# Linking to Catholic Catechism

Tags: discussion, catholicism

the USCCB finally has published an easily linked to catechism, which unfortunately only produces text based pages (but it's a start)

http://www.usccb.org/beliefs-and-teachings/what-we-believe/catechism/catechism-of-the-catholic-church/epub/index.cfm

There's also the [this site](http://www.scborromeo.org/ccc/ccc_toc2.htm) which has uncannilly high google page rankings for a parish website and the [vatican's Catechism](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG0015/_INDEX.HTM) which is abysmally unlinkable (unless you find a good footnote with an anchor to backtrack)

So what's the best way of linking Catholic Catechisms?

Answer (score 4):

I've found that the [*vatican.va catechism*](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG0015/_INDEX.HTM) works well -- as long as one links to the relevant subsection. Each of the catechism's end pages appears to contain less than ten statements, with the max length of each statement being about a hundred words. That, along with the fact that each statement is individually numbered, means that the apparent lack of anchors for individual statements is, IMO, not problematic.

Answer (score 3):

The USCCB version looks good! It's useful to be able to link to a specific paragraph (even though there's no exposed interface for it) and the full-text search seems speedy.

It would be *even better* if they hyperlinked the Scriptural and other documents referenced in the footnotes (so instead of popping up "LG 7" it would say "*Lumen Gentium* 7" and link to the actual text), but perhaps that will come in time.

I think the only advantage of the Vatican version (given that it and the USCCB site are just as "official") is that they have multiple language editions. Christianity.SE is in English so I don't think this issue has too much weight; people who are not so comfortable with English might like to cross-check with a version in their own language, but that would be the case for many sources we cite. If for some reason it was necessary to compare different language versions, talk about the use of a specific Latin word, etc., then the Vatican site is always available. Otherwise the USCCB version seems to me to be the best.